# Changing a word using gettext filter

Tags: php, gettext, code-snippets

I'm really new to PHP so please be gentle :-)
I want to use Code Snippets and change the word Lottery to Competition.

Would I use the `gettext` filter?

Thank you

```
<?php
/**
 * Lottery info template
 *
 */

if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit; // Exit if accessed directly
global $product, $post;

$min_tickets                = $product->get_min_tickets();
$max_tickets                = $product->get_max_tickets();
$lottery_participants_count = !empty($product->get_lottery_participants_count()) ? $product->get_lottery_participants_count() : '0';
$lottery_dates_to           = $product->get_lottery_dates_to();
$lottery_dates_from         = $product->get_lottery_dates_from();
$lottery_num_winners        = $product->get_lottery_num_winners();

?>
<p class="lottery-end"><?php echo __( 'Lottery ends:', 'wc_lottery' ); ?> <?php echo  date_i18n( get_option( 'date_format' ),  strtotime( $lottery_dates_to ));  ?>  <?php echo  date_i18n( get_option( 'time_format' ),  strtotime( $lottery_dates_to ));  ?> <br />
        <?php printf(__('Timezone: %s','wc_lottery') , get_option('timezone_string') ? get_option('timezone_string') : __('UTC+','wc_lottery').get_option('gmt_offset')) ?>
</p>

<?php if($min_tickets &&($min_tickets > 0)  ) : ?>
        <p class="min-pariticipants"><?php  printf( __( "This lottery has a minimum of %d tickets", 'wc_lottery'), $min_tickets ); ?></p>
<?php endif; ?> 

<?php if( $max_tickets  &&( $max_tickets > 0 )  ) : ?>
        <p class="max-pariticipants"><?php  printf( __( "This lottery is limited to %s tickets", 'wc_lottery' ),$max_tickets ) ; ?></p>
<?php endif; ?>

<p class="cureent-participating"> <?php _e( 'Tickets sold:', 'wc_lottery' )?> <?php echo  $lottery_participants_count ;?></p>

<?php if(  $lottery_num_winners > 0  ) : ?>

<p class="max-pariticipants"><?php  printf( _n( "This lottery will have %d winner" , "This lottery will have %d winners", $lottery_num_winners , 'wc_lottery' ) ,$lottery_num_winners ) ; ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could (but you should not!) simply make the word "lottery" or "competition" a placeholder:

```
<?php printf(__("This %s is limited to %s tickets.", $type, $max_tickets))?>
```

But don't do it!

In general, it is a bad idea to assemble translatable strings in the code because that will not work for other languages. For example, the two sentences would be translated into German as:

- *Diese Lotterie* ist auf %s Tickets begrenzt.
- *Dieser Wettbewerb* ist auf %s Tickets begrenzt.

The word *before* lottery/competition changes as well in German because the nouns have different genders.

Instead be more verbose like this:

```
<?php
    if ($type == 'lottery') {
        printf(__("This lottery is limited to %s tickets.", $max_tickets));
    } else {
        printf(__("This competition is limited to %s tickets.", $max_tickets));
    }
?>
```

Now your `po` file will contain two distinct strings, and they can be translated into any language.